# How to customize settings for a certain path in sublime 3 project?

Tags: sublimetext3

For example, I want to clang-format do format_on_save but only for files in certain folder, or mb at least files with certain scope or extension.

I know SyntaxMgr can do some of that, but it seems to only have global settings, while I want it to be project-specific.